# PHP preg_match: getting a full word

Tags: php, regex

I, have a text that reads something like:

```
....text....
listname: mylistname
....text....
name: John Smith
```

I am trying to obtain the name of the person, however using preg_match like the following: `preg_match('#name:\s\w{0,}\s\w{0,}#', $body, $arrNameMatches)`

I get "mylistname"... What can I add to that pattern so that it gets `name:` as a full word only, hence getting 'John Smith'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a word anchor before `name`:

```
preg_match('#\bname:\s\w{0,}\s\w{0,}#', $body, $arrNameMatches)
```

Alternatively, if you are sure that `name` will always occur at the beginning of the input, you can use a "begin of input" anchor, ie `^`:

```
preg_match('#^name:\s\w{0,}\s\w{0,}#', $body, $arrNameMatches)
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `listname:` contain the same pattern as `name:` => name:

use `^` at the beginning so that you say "the string must start with name"

```
preg_match('#^name:\s\w{0,}\s\w{0,}#', $body, $arrNameMatches)
```

Comment: Not the word, the _input_. Regexes have no notions of words.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$body = <<<_EOF
listname: List of Jerks
name: John Smith
name: Ted Danson
name: Buddy Holly
_EOF;

preg_match_all('/\bname: ([A-Za-z ]*)/', $body, $arrNameMatches);
print_r($arrNameMatches[1]);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => John Smith
    [1] => Ted Danson
    [2] => Buddy Holly
)
```

`\b` is equivalent to matching `\W` [non-word characters, ie: newlines] and `^` [beginning of input].